# Can a FB App "via appName" link to our Fan Page? - What do you do?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-page, facebook-apps

I created a FB App to facilitate FB Connect authentication on my [website](http://boothchat.com).

Users can share content from my site to Facebook via the same FB app.

We also created a FB Fan Page to grow our community reach.

However a FB App is a separate entity than a Fan Page, whatever content is shared via our website to FB the App link sends the users to an empty App page while all the fuzz is in our Fan page.

I did an extensive research for this issue and only came up with this useful post here in stackoverflow: "[Fan page vs Application Page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5408090/fan-page-vs-application-page)".

Ideally i'd want the App link ("... via appName") on every shared item to point to our fan page.

I need to know if this is an issue that FB needs to address, if i am missing something and what do you do to solve this situation

Answer (score 1):

Some apps are able to do this :

- http://mediafeedia.com/pro/
- http://www.postplanner.com/white-label-facebook-app/

I also would be interested to know how they do this.
I've checked all app settings...

Answer (score 0):

No, the App attribution on posts made via the API returns the user to that app's profile page - you'd need to have information there directing them back to your brand page if that's where you want them to go after they end up there.

I think in most cases people would click the name of the page or one of the links in the post rather than that small link at the bottom, no?

Comment: Problem is i can't do much with the App Page. Currently, i can't add a custom tab, the **only** thing i can change for the Info Page is "Description" so there is **currently no way** to redirect users from my App Page to my Fan Page :(

Comment: you could make the default tab the wall and put a post there pointing people to the brand page? (maybe attach a photo to it to draw the eye?)

Comment: That's a good tip! I did it :) Thanks... Looks like a bandaid on a bullet would though :/

Comment: There's a bug report about not being able to add tabs to app pages, i'm not sure what the status is of that though - maybe there's a better long term solution on the way